# Elegant way to search for installed DEB packages in C code

Tags: c

My CompSci Prof gave me the task to create a simplistic C installation program. I have to search for specified DEB packages in Ubuntu and if the package not found, inform user about this and abort the program. I have implemented two ways 1)parsing `popen`'s output for the `apt-get install`, and then 2) using `grep` to parse `dpkg -l`. Both ways work perfectly well, but my Prof calls them ugly approaches. Is there any non-ugly way, e.g. some specific non-Posix UBUNTU API function?

Comment: This specification "*I have to search for specified DEB packages in Ubuntu and if the package not found, inform user about this and abort the program.*" sound more like a test-if-a-certain-package-is-installed program.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I gotta do first! That's a part of my task.

Comment: Perhaps this http://dpkg.alioth.debian.org/doc/index.html helps?

Comment: You are a great man, @alk! Never before heard 'bout this library but browsing thru its API docu, eventually found what i want. I really am very grateful. Why don't you rewrite your suggestion as an answer. I'm gonna give you THE PROBLEM SOLVED mark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the Debian Package Management functionallity there is this library: http://dpkg.alioth.debian.org/doc/index.html

However be warned about the following from its `README.api` file (as per version 1.16.15 of the Debian package `libdpkg-dev`):

> What: libdpkg.a (C static library)
>
> Status: volatile
>
> Description:
>
> The API provided by this library is highly volatile, still in the process
>    of being cleaned up. It's only supposed to be used internally by dpkg for
>    now. Header files, functions, variables and types might get renamed,
>    removed or change semantics. If you still have a need to use it, which
>    you'd be doing anyway, say by locally building dpkg to get the library,
>    then define the C preprocessor macro LIBDPKG_VOLATILE_API in your build
>    to acknowledge that fact.

Comment: Thanks again! 5 minutes to give me what I have searched for in the last 5 days!!!